# Adding onto a variable with each recursive call?

Tags: c++, function, recursion, sum, variable-assignment

The aim is for the the function to end the recursion once 10 has been reached. I have tried printing out cartLimit to get an understanding on what is going wrong. At the moment in every recursion call the cartLimit is just overwritten by the new itemQuant inputted rather than the itemQuant being added onto the previous itemQuant within the cartLimit variable. Also even when I outright enter in 10 or a number above 10 as the itemQuant the function still continues to call itself.

```
double buyingItems(){

    double itemPrice;
    cout << "Please enter the item price: ";
    cin >> itemPrice;
    
    int itemQuant;
    cout << "Please enter item quantity: ";
    cin >> itemQuant;

    double totalCost = totalCost + itemPrice*itemQuant;

    int cartLimit = cartLimit + itemQuant;
    if(cartLimit != 10) {
    buyingItems();
    }else{
    return totalCost;
}
}
```

Comment: Recursion isn't a good way to solve this. Just add stuff to a `std::vector<CartItem>` or such, and keep track that the size doesn't exceeds the limit. And do that in a class for heavens Sake.

Comment: And if you really need to solve this with recursion then you should probably pass an argument to the function (and not ignore the return value)

Comment: In general, don't let the user control recursion. By mistake or malice they WILL recurse too deeply and overflow the stack.

Comment: Each function call has a separate `totalCost` variable which is not returned to the one outside it.

Comment: This doesn't compile, it's missing a }

Comment: `double totalCost = totalCost` is most certainly reading a variable before it has been initialized.  That's Undefined Behavior.  Same with `int cartLimit = cartLimit`.  It would probably benefit you greatly to [enable compiler warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/bdYGeWhsn).

Comment: Every recursive call has it's own set of variables. If you want to pass information from one recursive call to the next then you must use function parameters. So make `cartLimit` a parameter to your recursive function for example. This situation is **exactly the same** as regular functions. because there is nothing different about recursive functions, they are just regular functions and operate by exactly the same rules.

Comment: I simplified and generalized the code so apologies if its unclear why I am using recursion. I was tasked with using recursion within the code as a prerequisite. Thank you for the std::vector suggestion. I'll research it now and use it to improve for the next time.

Answer (score 1):

Every function call has its own set of local variables.

**Recursion is not special.**

Here's that code again, but I hid the function name so you can't tell which function it is. Also your code is missing a `}` so I fixed that.

```
double XXXXXXXXX(){

    double itemPrice;
    cout << "Please enter the item price: ";
    cin >> itemPrice;
    
    int itemQuant;
    cout << "Please enter item quantity: ";
    cin >> itemQuant;

    double totalCost = totalCost + itemPrice*itemQuant;

    int cartLimit = cartLimit + itemQuant;
    if(cartLimit != 10) {
        buyingItems();
    } else {
        return totalCost;
    }
}
```

So what does this function do? It asks for the price and quantity. Then it makes a new variable `totalCost`, then calculates `totalCost + itemPrice*itemQuant` (a random garbage number, possibly, because `totalCost` has no sensible number in it yet) and saves that in the variable `totalCost`.

Then it calculates the `cartLimit` (using the same approach including the random garbage number), and it maybe calls `buyingItems` - if `buyingItems` does any interesting stuff then it happens at this step - and or maybe it returns the `totalCost` that it calculated earlier. If it doesn't return `totalCost` then it possibly returns a garbage number or crashes, because there's no return instruction.

Notice: None of the code inside `{ buyingItems(); }` has anything to do with the `totalCost` or the `cartLimit` variables. It can't because it doesn't have any way to access those variables. Maybe `buyingItems` has its own variable inside it called `cartLimit`, but that's a different variable because it's declared in a different function call.

---

With that in mind, can you figure out why the function `XXXXXXXXX` doesn't do what you want?

Comment: I see what you mean. My variables are both not clearly defined is being assigned random garbage numbers and with each recursion I'm just creating brand new variables with said random garbage value. I've gone back and worked on this and I have now got it working. Thank you for helping me understand and improve my code.

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ and almost every programming language in the last 50 years has a concept of a "stack" and a "function local context".

Each function call has its own state of local variables.  When you recursively call the same function, the new call gets a completely separate copy of those local variables.

Now, in some older languages, this wasn't true.  But it is true in almost every modern language.

```
double buyingItems(){
  double itemPrice;
  cout << "Please enter the item price: ";
  cin >> itemPrice;

  int itemQuant;
  cout << "Please enter item quantity: ";
  cin >> itemQuant;

  double totalCost = totalCost + itemPrice*itemQuant;

  int cartLimit = cartLimit + itemQuant;
  if(cartLimit != 10) {
    buyingItems();
  }else{
    return totalCost;
  }
}
```

And yes, this means no addition beyond what your code says happens goes on.

What I'd suggest you do is pass **in** the remaining cart limit, and pass **out** the cost.  Then add it up.

```
double buyingItems(int cartLimit = 10, double existingCost = 0.)
{
  double itemPrice;
  std::cout << "Please enter the item price: ";
  std::cin >> itemPrice;

  int itemQuant;
  std::cout << "Please enter item quantity: ";
  std::cin >> itemQuant;

  double totalCost = itemPrice*itemQuant + existingCost;

  if(itemQuant < cartLimit)
  {
    return buyingItems(cartLimit - itemQuant, totalCost);
  }

  return totalCost;
}
```

Here, I pass in the accumulated cost and the room left in the cart as arguments, defaulted to 10 and 0 respectively.